# OSX: read raw keyboard input in C

Tags: c, macos, input, keyboard, driver

i'm playing with the modification of a cheap graphic-tablet. there are hot-keys on the tablet which don't work as i want and i'd like to modify them.

i.e: one of the hotkeys outputs a "+" (plus), another outputs a "-" (minus), etc.

my goal is to read the input of that specific "keyboard" (not the global user input), check for the value and post a custom CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent.

i successfully got the tablet to control the mouse-movement with CGEventCreateMouseEvent.

my theories so far:

#### 1. access keyboard with hidapi

- read directly from keyboard
- check for the hex value
- do some c-code
- problem here: hot-keys are not present in raw hid-output

#### 2. access global user inputs

- read any input on user-level
- check the source of the input (i.e: mac-keyboard, cheap-keyboard)
- do some c-code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

solved it!
with a little help from this guide: https://github.com/sdegutis/mjolnir/issues/9

basically what you need to do is:

- create an EventTap within an RunLoop and a fallback-function for the event
- type something on your normal keyboard and on the keyboard you want to hack into
- you should see an unique number for each keyboard
- use this value for your condition

```c
MY_DEBUGGED_KEYBOARD 44
int keyboard = 0;

CGEventRef
myCGEventCallback(CGEventTapProxy proxy, CGEventType type,
    CGEventRef event, void *refcon) {
// Paranoid sanity check.
if ((type != kCGEventKeyDown) && (type != kCGEventKeyUp))
    return event;

keyboard = CGEventGetIntegerValueField(event, kCGKeyboardEventKeyboardType);

// if you found your keyboard-value...
if (keyboard != MY_DEBUGGED_KEYBOARD) {
    return event;
}


// ... you can proceed with your stuff... i.e. remap input, etc.

printf("%d\n", keyboard);


// Set the modified keycode field in the event.
CGEventSetIntegerValueField(event, kCGKeyboardEventKeycode, (int64_t) keycode);

// We must return the event for it to be useful.
return event;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
CFMachPortRef      eventTap;
CGEventMask        eventMask;
CFRunLoopSourceRef runLoopSource;

// Create an event tap. We are interested in key presses.
eventMask = ((1 << kCGEventKeyDown) | (1 << kCGEventKeyUp));
eventTap = CGEventTapCreate(kCGSessionEventTap, kCGHeadInsertEventTap, 0,
        eventMask, myCGEventCallback, NULL);
if (!eventTap) {
    fprintf(stderr, "failed to create event tap\n");
    exit(1);
}

// Create a run loop source.
runLoopSource = CFMachPortCreateRunLoopSource(kCFAllocatorDefault, eventTap, 0);

// Add to the current run loop.
CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), runLoopSource, kCFRunLoopCommonModes);

// Enable the event tap.
CGEventTapEnable(eventTap, true);

// Set it all running.
CFRunLoopRun();
return 0;
}
```